# Applying lru_cache to Django template filter

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to define a `lru_cache`-ed template filter.

Django examines function code in order to verify appropriacy of filter calls in templates, but `lru_cache`covers my real signature, so calling such filter always fails with

`%s requires 0 arguments, %d provided`

error.

**Django 1.8.11, Python 2.7.10.** Means that I have no `functools.lru_cache`, instead I use Django's compatibility version: `django.utils.functional.lru_cache`.

Example:

```
from django.tepmlate import Library
from django.utils.functional import lru_cache

register = Library()

@register.filter
@lru_cache()
def my_filter(foobar):
    # do complex foobar stuff..
    return foobar ** 2
```

I thought `functools.wraps` could help me somehow but it's only good for  shallow introspection -- attributes like `__name__`, etc., or my "`wraps`-fu" is weak.

Obviously I can define a separate function with `lru_cache` and call it normally inside of the real filter function:

```
@lru_cache()
def _my_filter(foobar):
    # do complex foobar stuff...
    return foobar ** 2

@register.filter
def my_filter(foobar):
    return _my_filter(foobar)
```

**Question**: Is there a more elegant way to do this? For example without having to create another function?